# Twitter API invalid URLRequestWithMethod using Swift

Tags: ios, swift, api, twitter

i'm trying to access the home_timeline request as per [this](https://dev.twitter.com/twitter-kit/ios/api) example.

However, I keep getting following error:

> > 'URLRequestWithMethod' with an argument list of type '(String, URL: String, parameters: NSArray, error: inout NSError?)'

```
func getHomeTimeLine(){
    var clientError:NSError?
    let params = []

    let request = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
        "GET",
        URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json",
        parameters: params,
        error: &clientError)

    if request != nil {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request) {
                (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
                if (connectionError == nil) {
                    var jsonError : NSError?
                    let json : AnyObject? =
                    NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data,
                        options: nil,
                        error: &jsonError)
                }
                else {
                    println("Error: \(connectionError)")
                }
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(clientError)")
    }

}
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 6):

Define params as a dictionary and use it.

> let params: Dictionary = Dictionary()

```
func getHomeTimeLine() {
    var clientError:NSError?
    let params: Dictionary = Dictionary<String, String>()

    let request: NSURLRequest! = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod(
        "GET",
        URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/home_timeline.json",
        parameters: params,
        error: &clientError)

    if request != nil {
        Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.sendTwitterRequest(request!) {
            (response, data, connectionError) -> Void in
            if (connectionError == nil) {
                var jsonError : NSError?
                let json : AnyObject? =
                NSJSONSerialization.JSONObjectWithData(data!,
                    options: nil,
                    error: &jsonError)

                // check for json data
                if (json != nil) {
                    println("response = \(json)")
                } else {
                    println("error loading json data = \(jsonError)")
                }
            }
            else {
                println("Error: \(connectionError)")
            }
        }
    }
    else {
        println("Error: \(clientError)")
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
let request: NSURLRequest? = Twitter.sharedInstance().APIClient.URLRequestWithMethod("GET", URL: "https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json",
        parameters: ["screen_name" : username,
            "count" : "20"] ,
        error: &clientError)
```

Answer (score 0):

Actually, the method signature where it says 'URL' has been changed to 'URLString' the correct / updated method call (in Objective C) looks like this:

NSDictionary *params = @{@"include_email": @"true", @"skip_status": @"true"};

NSError *clientError;

NSURLRequest *request = [client URLRequestWithMethod:@"GET" URLString:@"https://api.twitter.com/1.1/account/verify_credentials.json" parameters:params error:nil];

Hope this helps someone!